# Iron Golem Farm not Dropping Iron Ingots

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have created an iron golem farm in a multiplayer server with raiding allowed. The farm is completely automatic, and kills the golems with lava. I am not having a problem with the golems spawning, they spawn. The lava is at their head level with water at their feet level to transport the drops. When they die, they only drop one poppy and no iron ingots. How can I fix this and make them drop iron? The farm works perfectly in single player creative mode.

Comment: The lava can't be burning the iron because I still get the roses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some servers restrict iron drops from iron golems to prevent the building of giant automated farms, or restrict any drops from environmentally-killed monsters, again, to prevent the creation of giant automated farms.

This might be done for gameplay reasons (no supplies of infinite free stuff) or for server lag reasons (no concentrations of hundreds or thousands of monsters collected in a tiny spot).

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that this is what happened. I'm going to have a talk with the owner!

Answer (score 6):

You may have to kill them by hand. Apparently there's a bug or change that makes mobs not drop the same stuff when they die as when they're killed personally, e.g., zombies won't drop iron unless you dispatch them personally, but only in SMP.

You might be able to change out the lava for a piston-based suffocator, timed so that it takes a fresh bunch of golems down to as few hearts as possible, then kill them by hand.

Comment: This is the same for skeletons, If you get a bunch on a heap and kill them all with for example a flint and steel. All they will drop are bones and arrows. But if you will kill them with your bare hands or any item of your choice they will also drop rares like bows and armour. I tested this in SP and MP both with the same result.

Comment: I know this is 7 years old, but for anyone wondering this is not a bug and never was a bug but an intended function where certain items are only dropped if killed by a player

Answer (score 2):

The Iron Golem should drop 3-5 iron and 0-2 roses. The lava could be burning the iron and not the roses because the  drops get launched at different angles. I would suggest you try this multiple times to make sure your results are valid.

Answer (score -3):

One reason the golems may not be dropping iron ingots is because you have to kill them yourself, kind of like XP, if **you** don't kill the mob, it wont drop XP. In this case, it's iron.
Mojang probably did this to slow down or stop automatic iron farms. But you still can have a farm, just take out the lava, make it so you are out of their hitting range but they are in your range and make a room (if you don't have one already) where they will "wait" to be killed. They don't drown either by the way. You could use your huge amount of cobblestone from mining to make swords that you would specifically use for your iron farm.

### Reducing their HP (I haven't tested this yet though)

You could take that lava and use it for the the same purpose but wont *kill* them you could make it where they fall through a 1 block (or 2) layer of lava before reaching the "waiting" room (if you did what I said above) this could reduce their HP enough to take only a few hits with a sword.